# nginx reverse proxy docker - filter by location

Tags: nginx, docker, reverse-proxy

I am following this article http://jasonwilder.com/blog/2014/03/25/automated-nginx-reverse-proxy-for-docker/ and I am wondering how "**filtering**" of requests by location (inspecting URL) can be set up.
For instance when request comes to www.example.com/a it will go to container A, when request comes to www.example.com/b it be redirected to container B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure two upstreams and redirect from /a to first one and from /b to second one. Something like this:

```
    upstream first {
      server 172.17.0.4:5000;
      server 172.17.0.3:5000;
    }

    upstream second {
      server 172.17.0.5:5000;
    }

    server {
    ...

        location /a {
            proxy_pass http://first;
            include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
        }

        location /b {
            proxy_pass http://second;
            include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
        }
    }
```

Comment: o.k., and how about the following option:

-when request comes to the URL: www.example.com -> it will be directed to container A
-when request comes to the URL: www.example.com/something -> it will be directed to container B

With variables like VIRTUAL_HOST, VIRTUAL_PORT I can't distinguish this.

Comment: Pretty much the same: you'll have to use blocks "location /" to point to container A and "location /something" to point to container B